# Stylus pen in Android

Tags: android, gesture-recognition, handwriting

I wish to implement a stylus pen in my android application.

i.e a user can write the text and it should be displayed in a text box.

I have no idea how it works or where to start with implementing this.

Are you able to provide guidance. Are there any tutorials I can use to get going?

Please help me.

Comment: what you mean by stylus pencil writer and then user can type? is user typing or using stylus?

Comment: did you mean handwriting recognition ?

Answer (score 0):

you could think about using the [Android Gesture Detection](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/gestures.html) and predefine some characters. This could work for you. Of course this won't be as precise as the input of the Samsung Galaxy Note or something as they have much more metrics.